# With React Native, how can I create an equal spaced header?

Tags: flexbox, react-native

How can I make a header with 4 equally spaced items in React Native?

Coming from a web dev background, the following flexbox produces 4 equally spaced items:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
      #header {
      display: flex;
            flex: 1;
            flex-direction: "row";
            height: 20px;
        }
        .item {
            flex: 1;
            background-color: red;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header">
        <div class="item">Item 1</div>
        <div class="item">Item 2</div>
        <div class="item">Item 3</div>
        <div class="item">Item 4</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

That HTML produces this:

[image]

However, with React Native, the same thing doesn't seem to work:

```
var navbarStyles = StyleSheet.create({
  navbar: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    height: 20
  },
  navbarItem: {
    flex: 1
  }
});

var Navbar = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <View style={navbarStyles.navbar}>
        <View style={navbarStyles.navbarItem}>
          <Text>Item 1</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={navbarStyles.navbarItem}>
          <Text>Item 2</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={navbarStyles.navbarItem}>
          <Text>Item 3</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={navbarStyles.navbarItem}>
          <Text>Item 4</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
});
```

[image]

Comment: Take a look at justifyContent

Answer (score 0):

Hi I did the above code and it works fine and gives output like the html example you have given above. And if you need to center align all text  instead of the beginning of each subview, you could use alignItems to 'center' at navbaritem.

I beleive you are facing the error because of the style of parent view above it. try fixing that. try giving a backgroundcolor to navbar and you will get some idea of issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this for parent

```
parent:{
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection:'row'
}
```

and then child items

```
child:{
        flex: 1,
    }
```